# Maybe inactivity should be considered when handing out moderating tools

Tags: discussion

I'm an inactive user who used to be active. I don't want to lose my reputation but I don't think I should have moderating tools and I wanted to open a discussion about whether user activity should be considered when handing out moderating tools

Comment: You could.... make a new account

Comment: You don't have to use the moderator tools. And if you *really* don't want the reputation, then put a bounty on a question that contained an answer that was really helpful to you and "donate" it to the answerer.

Comment: @Larnu I'm not gonna use them, duh, I just think maybe I shouldn't have gotten them in the first place. I didn't realize I could gift reputation but that's actually a pretty cool idea

Comment: @Larnu what answer on SO that you gave are you most proud of

Comment: I honestly have no idea, @yuvi , I have almost 2,000 answers on SO. But *please* don't go giving me a bounty. You *earned* that reputation, so use it for something relevant to you (and according to your tags, we have very little overlap in skill sets :) )

Comment: I would strongly advice against setting bounties just to "dump rep". First of all, due to a maximum bounty of `500`, you'd have to set 30-something of them, but mostly because it just skews the balance. I'm pretty sure it might even be considered "abuse" of the system.

Comment: But, @Nick , imagine not being able to comment on questions again for clarification or advise them that they have (major) security flaws in their code. Makes me feel sick... 

Comment: @Larnu yeah no I was kinda joking, but seriously - I don't wanna give away my reputation I know I earned it (maybe I'll give some if I see a good answer). What I want is to not have moderating powers.

Comment: Coupling some privileges to other metrics besides reputation is not a bad idea. I'm pretty sure it was brought up before, although I can't find the post right now. Maybe you can edit the question so it's more about that, and less about your personal situation?

Comment: @yivi yeah I just did

Comment: Technically some privileges are (kind of) coupled to other metrics. Being a "gold badger" for example isn't just simply having a score (not reputation) of 1,000 in a tag. You need to be active in said tag by contributing at least 200 (non-wiki) answers.

Comment: @Larnu That's good. maybe it should be done more

Comment: I think it would be really beneficial here if you explain *what* privileges you think you shouldn't have, or shouldn't be (as) trusted with. Then we can try to think of alternative ways to gain those privileges.

Comment: What would you consider the criteria for being inactive to lose the privileges and for the activity to gain them back again?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not sure. I just know I'm not an active part of the community and it seems weird that I have all these moderating tools

Comment: Are you concerned about someone hijacking a high rep, inactive account to cause problems? That's the only potential issue I can see but it wouldn't be that much different than an active account being hijacked.

Comment: @BSMP yeah I'd argue inactive users are an better target, because their users might not notice suspicious activity. It's definitely something worth considering

Answer (score 9):

There's not a lot that can be done here.

Sure, you could theoretically dump rep by setting bounties, but the best solution is really simple:

Just don't use your gained privileges if you're not comfortable using them.

Comment: Of course I'm not gonna use them. But maybe we should consider user activity when issuing moderating powers. Just seems reasonable

Comment: Also I don't wanna lose my reputation, I earned it. I just don't think it should be coupled with moderating tools

Comment: That's how Stack Exchange decided that would give users additional privileges though, @yuvi . If (high reputation) user do abuse/misuse their privileges though, they can be removed. (This is ***not*** me suggesting you abuse them to get them removed!)

Comment: @Larnu "That's how X decided" - so it can't ever be changed or discussed? come on.  Also you're (a) losing out on all the very active users with lower reputations who might contribute and (b) If I was a nefarious hacker, I would find powerful inactive users as a very good avenue of attack

Comment: I didn't say it couldn't be changed , no @yuvi . But the context of your question has changed *significantly* now, which does invalidate several of the points raised here or make them less contextual; my comment was specifically about your scenario, and SE certainly wouldn't change their design for one person.

Comment: @Larnu Nah I just wasn't clear about what I meant.

Comment: @Larnu yeah I was just giving myself as an example, I wasn't making a personal request

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, I think the site has more problems "recruiting" enough volunteers to keep up with the curation work that needs doing than interest in limiting/throtteling who may curate.

Certainly curation *quality* has precedence over quantity. On the other hand, from personal experience and observation there is a definite learning curve involved in curation. It takes time and interest (whether for rep points or other reasons) to learn about reviewing.

I don't see how "activity" - however you want to define it, you don't say, specifically - would be a better indicator than reputation. Some people with low "activity" might be very good curators, just as some with high rep might be. And the opposite can be just as true.

Either an individual has the interest and "talent", or they haven't. How they use the site, beyond the knowledge of its guidelines, isn't important in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking reputation is not a good measurement for good moderators. Maybe a better system is one where the more you moderate the more tools become available. It means people who spend their time bettering the site would gradually get to have more power in doing so, which would also serve as an incentive as well

Comment: @yuvi It's important to distinguish between "moderator" and "curator". A moderator has a diamond next to their screen name (so far, none have participated in this discussion). A moderator is elected by the site users (you, me - everyone with an account) to perform even "higher level" clean-up tasks (with more powerful tools) - we sometimes even refer to them as "janitors". To become a moderator, a certain rep minimum is required, but so are other things. So, as far as *moderation* goes, what you propose in your comment is already fact.

Comment: The vast majority of us are "curators": those who do they day-to-day jobs that support site quality. To a certain extent, what you suggest is already in-place: suggested edits that are approved assigns points up to 2k rep. That opens up a number of tools. Beyond that... There is some question whether those who are not active contributors in the Q&A side and thus divorced from the actual purpose of the site, should acquire so much power. We've seen it on the Meta site, in the past: ...

Comment: ...there have been people who've centered their participation on Meta, rather than Main and began to dictate policy in ways that tended to work at cross-purposes with reasonable actions. (Think "rules lawyers".) So it's something of a balancing act.